# For loop for copying files of a path list using shutil.copytree() python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, path

I'm developing a script in python 3 that reads a samba config file of users and paths of shared folders. The scripts must backup the shared folders to a USB device.

I'm having a problem copying the folders because my code stays on the first path of paths list

**EDIT 1**

The problem seems to be in:

```
            for path in paths:
                #Se reemplaza el string ruta por la ruta completa hasta los archivos sin 'path = ' 
                path = path.replace('path = ', '')
                #Ruta del directorio (carpeta compartida)
                dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(path))
                #Nombre de la carpeta contenedora (carpeta compartida)
                basename = os.path.basename(path)
                print(path + ' respaldado en ' + usb_path + '/' + basename)
                shutil.copytree(path, usb_path + '/' + basename)
                return dirname
```

**EDIT 2**

here's the code:

backup.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Nov  5 08:40:56 2019

@author: Juan Carlos Reyes Suazo
"""

import shutil
import os

class backup:

    archive = input('Escriba la ruta de su archivo smb.conf: ')
    usb_path = input('Escriba la ruta de su dispositivo USB: ')  

    #Metodo que lee el archivo de texto smb.conf, guarda los usuarios y las rutas y copia las carpetas de dichas rutas en el USB
    def read_file_copy_backup(archive, usb_path):
        #Abre el archivo y lo lee
        with open(archive) as file:
            #Busca la linea 9610
            file.seek(9610)
            tuple_list = list()
            #Recorre el archivo linea por linea
            for line in file:
                #Separa las lineas
                line = line.strip()
                if not line:
                    continue
                #Separa la linea nuevamente para quitar los [] y anade el elemento a la lista de lineas
                tuple_list.append(line)
#            print(tuple_list)
#            Crea tuplas users y paths
            users = list()
            paths= list()
#            #Recorre la tupla de lineas
            for element in tuple_list:
                #Si el elemento empieza con '[' se anade a la tupla users
                if element.startswith('['):
                    users.append(element)
                #Si el elemento empieza con 'path = ' se reemplaza 'path = ' por '' y se anade a la tupla paths
                if element.startswith('path = '):
                    paths.append(element) 
            for path in paths:
                #Se reemplaza el string ruta por la ruta completa hasta los archivos sin 'path = ' 
                path = path.replace('path = ', '')
                #Ruta del directorio (carpeta compartida)
                dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(path))
                #Nombre de la carpeta contenedora (carpeta compartida)
                basename = os.path.basename(path)
                print(path + ' respaldado en ' + usb_path + '/' + basename)
                shutil.copytree(path, usb_path + '/' + basename)
                return dirname

    read_file_copy_backup(archive, usb_path)
```

smb.conf file from line 9610 till end of file

```
[prueba]
    comment = prueba
    path = /home/servidor/Documentos/prueba
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = servidorftp

[Compartido-proyectos]
    path = /home/fsoto/Documentos/Compartido-proyectos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = aigor, fsoto, pbarriento, rsolis

[marearoja]
    comment = marearoja
    path = /home/marearoja/Documentos/
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = labpm, marearoja

[finanzas]
    comment = finanzas
    path = /home/finanzas/Documentos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = finanzas

[Auditoria]
    comment = auditoria
    path = /home/auditores/Documentos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = auditores

[saludocupacional]
    comment = saludocupacional
    path = /home/saludocupacional/Documentos/saludocupacional
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = hcordero, saludocupacional

[docsOsorno]
    comment = documentos
    path = /home/osorno/Documentos/documentos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = osorno

[profmed]
    comment = profmed
    path = /home/profmed/Documentos/profmed
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = profmed

[ugp]
    comment = ugp
    path = /home/ugp/Documentos/ugp
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = ugp

[CONTROL DE GESTION]
    comment = CONTROL DE GESTION
    path = /home/controlgestion/Documentos/CONTROL DE GESTION
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = controlgestion

[tabaco]
    comment = tabaco
    path = /home/tabaco/Documentos/tabaco
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = tabaco

[formalizaciones]
    comment = formalizaciones
    path = /home/formalizaciones/Documentos/formalizaciones
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = formalizaciones

[alimentos]
    path = /home/alimentos/Documentos/alimentos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = alimentos
    comment = alimentos

[exenciones de arancel]
    comment = exenciones de arancel
    path = /home/arancel/Documentos/exenciones de arancel
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = arancel, oirsch, servidorftp

[proyectos de sentencia chiloe]
    comment = proyectos de sentencia chiloe
    path = /home/sumarios/Documentos/proyectos de sentencia chiloe
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = servidorftp, sumarios

[programa intercultural]
    comment = programa intercultural
    path = /home/intercultural/Documentos/programa intercultural
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = intercultural, promotorsalud, promoyparticipacion, saludpublica

[Compartido-proyectos]
    path = /home/fsoto/Documentos/Compartido-proyectos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = aigor, fsoto, pbarriento, rsolis

[licencias medicas]
    comment = licencias medicas
    path = /home/licmed/Documentos/licencias medicas
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = licmed

[Cumplimiento y evaluacion AGUAS Programa 2015]
    comment = Cumplimiento y evaluacion AGUAS Programa 2015
    path = /home/aguas/Documentos/Cumplimiento y evaluacion AGUAS Programa 2015
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = aguachiloe, aguaosorno, aguapalena, aguapmontt, salud_ambiental, unidadaguachiloe

[sgc]
    comment = sgc
    path = /home/sgc/Documentos/sgc
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = alimentoscomp2017, formalizacion, sgc

[respaldos]
    path = /media/servidorftp/respaldo/respaldos
    writeable = yes
    browseable = no
    valid users = servidorftp
    comment = respaldos

[entel]
    comment = entel
    path = /home/entel/Documentos/entel
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = entel, rmunoz, servidorftp

[depto dsp]
    comment = depto dsp
    path = /home/dsp/Documentos/depto dsp
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = dsp, promotorsalud, promoyparticipacion, saludpublica

[videosSeremi]
    comment = videosSeremi
    path = /home/servidorftp/videosSeremi
;   writeable = No
    browseable = no
    guest ok = yes

[uso]
    comment = uso-chiloe
    path = /home/uso-chiloe/Documentos/uso
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = uso-chiloe

[Documentos]
    path = /home/discapacidad-chiloe/Documentos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = discapacidad-chiloe

[discapacidadchiloe]
    comment = discapacidadchiloe
    path = /home/discapacidad-chiloe/Documentos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = discapacidad-chiloe

[pmg]
    comment = pmg
    path = /home/pmg/Documentos/pmg
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = pmg

[Emergencia marea roja Osorno]
    comment = Emergencia marea roja Osorno
    path = /home/mro/Documentos/Emergencia marea roja Osorno
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = mro

[Deis]
    comment = Deis
    path = /home/deis/Documentos/Deis
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = deis

[labpm]
    comment = labpm
    path = /home/labpm/Documentos/labpm
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = labpm, labpml

[abastecimiento]
    comment = abastecimiento
    path = /home/abastecimiento/Documentos/abastecimiento
;   writeable = No
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes

[rrhh]
    comment = rrhh
    path = /home/rrhh/Documentos/rrhh
;   writeable = No
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes

[cmpregional]
    comment = cmpregional
    path = /home/compin/Documentos/cmpregional
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = compin

[dspchiloe]
    comment = dspchiloe
    path = /home/dspchiloe/Documentos/dspchiloe
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = dspchiloe, laboratoriocastro

[monitoreo_osorno]
    comment = monitoreo_osorno
    path = /home/monitoreos/Documentos/monitoreo_osorno
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = monitoreos

[residuos llanquihue]
    comment = residuos llanquihue
    path = /home/residuos/Documentos/residuos llanquihue
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = aguachiloe, aguapmontt, aigor, fsoto, hcordero, residuos, rparra

[Formalizacion OirsPm]
    comment = Formalizacion OirsPm
    path = /home/formalizacion/Documentos/Formalizacion OirsPm
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = formalizacion

[promoyparticipacion]
    comment = promoyparticipacion
    path = /home/promoyparticipacion/Documentos/promoyparticipacion
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = dsp, eupalimentos, promoyparticipacion

[test]
    comment = test
    path = /home/test/Documentos/test
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = test

[alimentoscomp2017]
    path = /home/alimentoscomp2017/Documentos/alimentoscomp2017
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = alimentoscomp2017, proyectoosorno, sgc
    comment = alimentoscomp2017

[EUPALIMENTOPROMOCION]
    path = /home/eupalimentos/Documentos/EUPALIMENTOPROMOCION
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = eupalimentos, promoyparticipacion, sgc
    comment = eupalimentopromocion

[promoyparticipacionl]
    comment = promoyparticipacionl
    path = /home/promoyparticipacion/Documentos/promoyparticipacion
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = eup, promotorsalud

[FiebreQ]
    path = /home/fiebreq/Documentos/FiebreQ
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = fiebreq

[respaldos-cobian]
    comment = respaldos-cobian
    path = /media/servidorftp/respaldo/respaldos-cobian
;   writeable = No
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = servidorftp

[Unidad Agua Chiloe]
    path = /home/unidadaguachiloe/Documentos/Unidad Agua Chiloe
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = aguachiloe, unidadaguachiloe

[Seremi]
    comment = seremi
    path = /home/seremi/Documentos/Seremi
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = seremi

[ugp formatos]
    comment = ugp formatos
    path = /home/ugp/Documentos/ugp formatos
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = ugp

[ugp formatos visita]
    comment = ugp formatos visita
    path = /home/ugp/Documentos/ugp formatos
;   writeable = No
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes

[saludambiental]
    comment = saludambiental
    path = /home/salud_ambiental/Documentos/planilla
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = aguapmontt, rparra, salud_ambiental, sgc

[EUP]
    path = /home/eup/Documentos/EUP
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = eup, promoyparticipacion, salud_ambiental

[EUPL]
    comment = EUPL
    path = /home/eup/Documentos/EUP
;   writeable = No
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = saludocupacional, usuariolectura

[saludambientalL]
    comment = saludambientalL
    path = /home/salud_ambiental/Documentos
;   writeable = No
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = usuariolectura

[labcastro]
    comment = labcastro
    path = /home/laboratoriocastro/Documentos/labcastro
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = dspchiloe, laboratoriocastro

[oirschiloe]
    comment = oirschiloe
    path = /home/oirsch/Documentos/oirschiloe
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = oirsch, servidorftp

[Sumarios Sanitarios Juridica]
    comment = Sumarios Sanitarios juridica
    path = /home/sumariosjur/Documentos/Sumarios Sanitarios Juridica
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = servidorftp, sumariosjur

[OirsQuellon]
    comment = OirsQuellon
    path = /home/oirsquellon/Documentos/OirsQuellon
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = oirsquellon

[OirsAncud]
    comment = OirsAncud
    path = /home/oirsancud/Documentos/OirsAncud
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = oirsancud

[Discapacidad Compin PM]
    comment = Discapacidad Compin PM
    path = /home/compinpm/Documentos/Discapacidad Compin PM
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = compinpm

[EPP]
    comment = EPP
    path = /home/epp/Documentos/EPP
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = epp

[gabinete]
    comment = gabinete
    path = /home/gabinete/Documentos/gabinete
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = gabinete

[informatica]
    comment = informatica
    path = /media/servidorftp/imagen/informatica
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = servidorftp

[Proyecto Osorno]
    comment = Proyecto Osorno
    path = /home/proyectoosorno/Documentos/Proyecto Osorno
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = alimentoscomp2017, proyectoosorno

[comite paritario chiloe]
    comment = comite paritario chiloe
    path = /home/cphysc/Documentos/comite paritario chiloe
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = cphysc, oirsch, servidorftp

[ComiteParitario]
    comment = ComiteParitario
    path = /home/cparitario/Documentos/ComiteParitario
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = compinpm, cparitario

[COMUNICACIONES]
    comment = COMUNICACIONES
    path = /home/comunicaciones/Documentos/COMUNICACIONES
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = comunicaciones

[soportetic]
    comment = soportetic
    path = /home/soportetic/Documentos/soportetic
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = servidorftp, soportetic

[ReunionesSeremi]
    comment = ReunionesSeremi
    path = /home/reuseremi/Documentos/ReunionesSeremi
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = reuseremi

[SeguridadLaboratoriosAmbientales]
    comment = SeguridadLaboratoriosAmbientales
    path = /home/seguridadlabam/Documentos/SeguridadLaboratoriosAmbientales
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = seguridadlabam

[Profmedx]
    comment = Profmedx
    path = /home/profmedx/Documentos/Profmedx
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = profmedx

[backup-cobian]
    path = /media/servidorftp/BACKUP/backup-cobian
;   writeable = No
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = servidorftp, soportetic

[labosorno]
    comment = labosorno
    path = /home/labosorno/Documentos/labosorno
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    valid users = labosorno
```

Im trying to copy every folder and it's content in the smb.config file

Comment: Are you sure  line = line.strip(), shouldn't be line.split()?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'll try with line.split()

Comment: Side note: `read_file_copy_backup` does not return a value - it makes no sense to run it within a `print` statement.

Comment: so you say it must return 
shutil.copytree(path, usb_path)
??

Comment: No, just call it without `print()` like this: `read_file_copy_backup(archive, usb_path)`. But as I said, this is just a note on your code and not related to your actual problem.

Comment: thanks anyway. My problem is that when I do: for path in paths: shutil.copytree(path, usb_path)
it only copies the first folder